# How to approximate an ellipse to fill a given rectangle, using bezier curves?

Tags: java, android, math

I tried the code below, which draws a good approximation of a circle if the rectangle's width is the same as its height; but it doesn't draw a great oval, the "corners" are very pointed.  Any suggestions?

```
float width = rect.width();
float height = rect.height();
float centerX = rect.width() / 2;
float centerY = rect.height() / 2;

float diameter = Math.min(width, height); 
float length = (float) (0.5522847498 * diameter/2);


path.moveTo(0, centerY);
path.cubicTo(0, centerY - length, 0, centerX - length, 0, centerX, 0);
path.cubicTo(centerX + length, 0, width, centerY - length, height, centerY);
path.cubicTo(width, centerY + length, centerX + length, height, centerX, height);
path.cubicTo(centerX - length, height, 0, centerY + length, 0, centerY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should scale `length` according to which axis it's on, so that the distance from each arc endpoint to the adjacent control points is (not fixed but) a fixed fraction of the axis you're moving parallel to at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a true rectangle, with right angles, then it should be easy.  The major and minor axes of the ellipse equal the lengths of the sides of the rectangle, and the center of the ellipse is located at the intersection of the rectangle's diagonals.

I don't know how to express it as Bezier splines off the top of my head, but the classic equation for an ellipse should be easy enough to write, as long as you transform to the appropriate coordinate system first (e.g. x-axis along the major axis of the rectangle/ellipse, y-axis along the minor axis of the rectangle/ellipse).